# Convert list to json file

Tags: java, json, collections, java-stream

I have a stream list, want to convert into json and save as json file.

The code looks as follow:

```
stream
          .map(e -> e.split(";"))
          .map(e -> {
            Industry in = new Industry();
            in.code = Integer.parseInt(e[0]);
            in.description = e[1];
            return in;
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
          .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.code));
```

How to convert into json and save as a file?

Thanks

Comment: Use your preferred JSON marshaller/mapper. There are dozens of them. Jackson is probably the most popular. Googling for "How to convert Java objects to JSON" should return dozens of result.

Comment: Your code is a convoluted way of doing the same as `stream .map(e -> e.split(";")) .forEach(e-> System.out.println(e[0]));`, everything else in-between being just a waste of resource. But most notably, it doesn’t produce anything that could be converted to json. So what’s the point?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer only and only to represent how in-class serialization would be much faster than using third-party serialization libraries such as Jackson.

For fast serialization, especially in case of distributed computing and heavy cross application communication, it is performance-wise to develop an interface or a base-class for this purpose. This is going to be similar, though not necessarily the same, to the following code:

```
public abstract class JsonCompatible {
    public abstract String jasonSerialize();
    public abstract void jasonDeserialize(String obj);
    protected String[] breakAsJson(String obj){
        return obj.substring(1, obj.length()-2).replace("\"", "").split(",");       
    } 
}
```

The data models or classes to be serialized can implement the interface or the example abstract class. In order to also address the question of the asker and provide a solution, I have developed an example for the `Industry` class.

```
public class Industry extends JsonCompatible {
    private String id, description;
    private int code;

    public Industry(String id, String description, int code) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.code = code;
    }
    public Industry(String id, String description, String code) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.code = Integer.parseInt(code);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = Integer.parseInt(code);
    }    
    public Industry() {
    }

    @Override
    public String jasonSerialize() {
        return String.format("{\"Id\":\"%s\", \"Code\":\"%d\", \"Description\":\"%s\"}", id, code, description);
    }

    @Override
    public void jasonDeserialize(String obj) {
        for(String i : breakAsJson(obj)){
            String[] expand = i.split(":");
            if(expand.length > 1){
                expand[0] = expand[0].trim();
                if(expand[0].equals("Id")){
                    id = expand[1];
                }
                else if (expand[0].equals("Code")){
                    setCode(expand[1]);
                }
                else if(expand[0].equals("Description")){
                    description = expand[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As represented in the example code, the `Industry` class is derived from `JsonCopatible`. At this point, we can develop an array serializer for serializing a collection of `Industry` objects and serialize it much faster than carried out by Jackson as follows.

```
public class JsonArray<T extends JsonCompatible> {
    private List<T> obj;
    private String namespace = "Default";
    public JsonArray(List<T> obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public JsonArray(List<T> obj, String namespace) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }

    public String getJasonArray(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"").append(namespace).append("\": [");
        List<String> elements = obj.stream().map(x-> x.jasonSerialize()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        int size = elements.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            sb.append(elements.get(i));
            if(i < size - 1){
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }
        sb.append("]}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It is very obvious that this is only an example of this approach and it has to be customized according to the needs and requirements of the project/asker. Since the array serialize works in a generic way, there will not be any redundant code involved, and since this is not relying on reflections (on which Jackson relies), it will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

We use jackson to convert objects into JSON

```java
        var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        var data = stream
          .map(e -> e.split(";"))
          .map(e -> {
            Industry in = new Industry();
            in.code = Integer.parseInt(e[0]);
            in.description = e[1];
            return in;
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

         var outputJsonFile = new FileOutputStream("data.json");
         objectMapper.writeValue(outputJsonFile, e);
```

Note: var is introduced in Java 10. Above code works with Java 11+ (stable release).

For more about `Jackson`:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: Not really a good idea to serialize each object one by one. Why not just serialize the whole list, and thus get a valid JSON file? Especially since this effectively only writes the last object to the file. And never closes the streams.

Comment: @JBNizet: `Not really a good idea to serialize each object one by one`. I think it is a really good idea if you do this by defining a method in your class for this purpose, because that will be extremely fast. Like for example when you need to clone objects in a list. Reason for this is that: no reflection would be needed.

Comment: @Transcendent how do you think Jackson transforms objects it knows nothing about to JSON, if not by using reflection? Also, the goal here is not to clone objects. It's to write a list of objects to a file.

Comment: @JBNizet: Those libraries are meant to behave that way, but if someone is after a very fast approach, dedication of a `Serialize` and `Deserialize` method inside your data model or your class it not only a good idea but also necessary. The scenario is for small models, Jackson would work just fine, but for heavy message passing, then it will cause a tremendous amount of lag.

Comment: @Transcendent: I don’t see, how your comment addresses in any way the difference between processing single items or an entire list at once. If you want to *just clone* objects and care for performance, neither, writing to a file nor converting to JSON in-between, is constructive. If you want to clone objects, just clone them.

Comment: @JB Nizet: but it fits perfectly to the code of the OP, as the entire task seems to be about processing text and producing text, with an obsolete parsing step, creation of a spurious irrelevant `Industry` instance and collecting everything into a `List`, just to call `forEach` on it…

Comment: @Holger: The difference is very clear. When you serialize a list using reflection, you have to detect the type, sneak into the type's data, get the values, marshal them and save. But when your type has a method for that, no type detection would be needed, no sneaking into the type would be needed, as it would just work like the `toString` method. It's unquestionable that this approach is faster and no one can deny it.

Comment: @Transcendent: there is no reason to process a `List` via Reflection. `List` is a well-known interface of the core API. Finding out whether each element “*has a method for that*” works the same, wether you specify a single object or a `List` of objects.

Comment: @Holger: That applies to a list of a primitive type, but what if you have a list of a complex type which has like 100 properties? Do you think without reflection, and without using my approach, you can serialize that list? (Unless you wanna write a dedicated for loop for every list, that cannot be done. And doing so is not efficient). You can develop an interface and implement it so that you can serialize the list in a generic way without relying on reflection.

Comment: @Transcendent: how does “you approach” serialize the elements of the list without iterating over the list, magic?

Comment: @Holger: As I explained, you have develop an interface which has two methods such as `String Serialize(), and void DeSerialize(T obj)`. Your data model must implement the interface, and then you can develop a generic method whose generic type would be for example `<T extends Serializable>`. Then you can effectively convert objects to JSON and vice versa (or even XML). I can write you the code as an answer if you are interested.

Comment: @Transcendent: So you *can* write a generic method that serializes an entire `List` based on that? And what do you say to someone ignoring the existence of your generic method? Perhaps the same as JB Nizet, i.e. that (s)he should use your method instead of redoing everything? Do you notice the point? The original comment was about processing single items vs processing an entire list, not about Reflection vs interfaces.

Comment: @Holger: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129235/discussion-between-transcendent-and-holger).

Comment: @Holger: I'm surprised that you even have not paid attention to my first comment, and what I highlighted. Anyways, happy to have talk to you :). As you said I should not waste my time explaining to you.

Comment: @Transcendent: Oh, by “I think it is a really good idea” you meant “I agree that this is ‘Not really a good idea’”? Do you notice the problem with the language there? You could really saved a lot of time…

Comment: @Holger: Please look at the previous block in my comment, and please try to ask an expert if Reflection would be better, or writing a for loop dedicated to each serialization, or my recommended generic approach. I have nothing to tell you, because you don't understand apparently.

Comment: @Transcendent: the problem is that you constantly try to change the topic. The initial comment, to which you responded, doesn’t say anything about Reflection. Again, the last time, really, it talks about *opening a new file for each object*. You comment reads like you are saying that opening a new file each time was a good idea. As you somehow seem to think, not opening a new file would prevent a Reflection-free solution. Anyway, since this answer doesn’t contain such a Reflection-free solution, you could have spent the time better by posting an answer with such a solution…